# Python prints numbers instead of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Tkinter program that displays what you enter but instead I get a bunch of numbers in the IDLE shell.

My program:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

    frame  = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()

    self.text_write = Entry(frame)
    self.text_write.pack()

    self.Show = Button(frame, text='Show', command=self.Show)
    self.Show.pack(side=RIGHT)

    def Show(self):
        Label(self.text_write.get())

 root = Tk()

 app = App(root)

 root.mainloop()
```

but instead of text being shown. Numbers appear in my IDLE shell such as:

```
.4334975024
.4334975600
.4334975672
.4334975816
.4334975960
.4334976104
.4334976248
.4334976392
.4334976536
```

would somebody please explain the problem and how I could fix it.

Comment: What is `App.Show()` (the original one) supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Why are you *replacing* `App.Show()` with a button on the instance? (`self.Show = Button(...)`). The `Button` action now points to itself.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Actually, the command is set during the constructor call and the old method is not disposed of even though the name is replaced. But I agree that this is bad practice.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: It's being shadowed, so the class method is not reachable from `self`. I was simplifying. :-)

Comment: It's not being shadowed, it's being replaced entirely. But not before a reference is passed to the `Button` constructor.

Answer (score 3):

```
def Show(self):
    Label(self.text_write.get())
```

If you replace "Label" with "print" it works (as in, prints the value to stdout)

What the code does as-is is create a new label with a string as a parent (when it wants a window as a parent), and then doesn't attach that label to anything.

You probably want to create the Label object and attach it to the window in **init**, and then update the label's value in Show()?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

    frame  = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()

    self.text_write = Entry(frame)
    self.text_write.pack()

    # rename the show button because you gave a member function the same name
    self.show_button = Button(frame, text='Show', command=self.Show)
    self.show_button.pack(side=RIGHT)

    # create label to display entered text
    self.display = Label(frame, text='')
    self.display.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def Show(self):
        # print text to the standard output
        print self.text_write.get()
        # show text on label
        self.display['text'] = self.text_write.get()

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i changed my code to this but an erroe message comes up:            Label instance has no attribute 'set'                                   would it be possible to fix this

Comment: @user2436777 Oops! Sorry! I didn't actually check the code. Try setting the labels `text` option. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, to you and everyone else who helped the program is now working.